# How to find a custom fragment from an inflated layout?

Tags: android

I have a custom fragment in a inflated layout, how to access it?
I have tried many ways after inflated, but none of them worked:

1. `getTransitionManager().findFragmentById(id_xxxxx)` returns null;
2. `getChildAt(x)`, get a View but not be able to cast to fragment;
3. I Tried to create a new fragment programmatically, and add to a container in the inflated view, but the app crashed says "No view found for id xxx for fragment fff"

code, I want to find `ReportCalenderFragment` and hold it:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    mCalendar = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dlg_choose_report, null);

    ConstraintLayout ly = (ConstraintLayout)mCalendar;
    RelativeLayout rly = (RelativeLayout)ly.getChildAt(0);
    LinearLayout lly = (LinearLayout)rly.getChildAt(0);
    View v = (View)lly.getChildAt(0);

    //lly.setId(R.id.report_calendar_con);
    //ReportCalenderFragment frag = new ReportCalenderFragment();
    //FragmentTransaction fragTrans = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    //fragTrans.add(R.id.report_calendar_con, frag);
    //fragTrans.commit();
    //ReportCalenderFragment frag = (ReportCalenderFragment)lly.getChildAt(0);

    ...
}
```

XML, `ConstraintLayout` was filtered by this text editor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/report_calendar_con"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#000"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/frag_calendar_rp"
                android:name="package.fragments.ReportCalenderFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Paste your code

Comment: @Sarath, code pasted

Comment: Are you inflating the layout inside a fragment?

Comment: @Sarath, Yes, I am. And this layout is used as a custom view in a Dialog

Comment: You mean, you have a fragment, where you show a dialog fragment, and inside that dialog fragment's layout you have another fragment?

Comment: @Sarath, a dialog was popout from a mother Fragment, this dialog holds a custom view (mCalendar), the mCalendar view was inflated from R.layout.dlg_choose_report. In mCalendar there's a custom fragment -"ReportCalenderFragment", now I want to find a way to hold that fragment in whatever way.

Comment: Check my answer, you can get a reference to  `ReportCalenderFragment` inside your dialog fragment in that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ReportCalenderFragment frag  = (ReportCalenderFragment) getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_calendar_rp);
```

If you are using `ReportCalenderFragment` inside a dialog, which is inside another fragment

You should use the `ChildFragmentmanager` from parent fragment while showing the dialog

```
MyDialogFragment dialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Comment: The ReportCalenderFragment is not inside another fragment, it's in a layout of the presented xml file. Actually I used getChildFragmentManager() before. I forgot to mention the code is in the onCreate() method of the mother fragment.

Comment: It seems DialogFragment is a much more appropriate method to deal with a custom dialog than inflating a view, your answer inspired me to use a DialogFragment instead , thx

Answer (score 0):

Like this：

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        ReportCalenderFragment fragment= (ReportCalenderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_calendar_rp);//this method
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),fragment.toString());
    }
```

Comment: There was no error in both fragment and layout, the app can display the inflated layout, but I want to hold the fragment to do something

Comment: Use getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById. Like this：

 ReportCalenderFragment fragment= (ReportCalenderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_calendar_rp);